# How to force at least one argument from a set in Docopt?

Tags: c#, docopt

I want my program to require at least one argument from a set in order for the arguments to be valid.

So for the sake of example, let's say I have 3 switches (-a, -b and -c) and two mandatory arguments.

These would be valid.

`myapp -a FOO BAR
myapp -a -b FOO BAR
myapp -a -c FOO BAR`

This would not be:

`myapp FOO BAR`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use ellipsis `...` to state that an option should appear one or more times:

```
Usage:
    myapp (-a|-b|-c)... <FOO> <BAR>
```

Here we state that either `-a`, `-b`, or `-c` should appear one or more times.

Accepts:

```
myapp -a FOO BAR
myapp -a -b FOO BAR
myapp -a -c FOO BAR
```

Rejects:

```
myapp FOO BAR
```

Comment: Wouldn't that allow the flags to be provided multiple times though? i.e. `myapp -a -a -b`. Not that it's a problem, it's just an observation.

Comment: Yes, that is true. If you want to avoid that, then you probably have to spell out all the combinations, and that would make the command line specification less user friendly. So it is kind of a tradeoff.

Comment: I can live with that.